# Multiple tables to json with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can you guys explain to me what’s the best way to export an extensive list of tables from various Oracle and SQL Server schemas in json format using Apache Spark? Can Spark handle multiples dataframes in the same application?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.. Assume that you have data in SQL Server and Oracle DB as well, create the connection in and load the data into two dataframe , post that you can use **`toJson`** or likewise functions and create your own json structure as per the requirement, in short, yes, spark can handle reading from multiple different source in a single application.

The reading from various source like - Oracle , PostGreSQL is easily available in google.